# Redis design for translation

Tags: redis, database, nosql

I would like to use Redis for translation

e.g. word: sunglasses and it's translation in Spanish and French.

should I use key value like:

```
sunglasses:fr lunettes de soleil
sunglasses:sp gafas de sol
```

or save it in Set data structure? 
or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using hashes instead, assuming you have a core vocabulary (e.g. in English), use the word itself a the key's name. That way, you can do:

```
HMSET sunglasses fr "lunettes de soleil" sp "gafas de sol" ...
```

To get the translation to French:

```
HGET sunglasses fr
```